# Equivalence of two metrics on countable product

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, product-space, box-topology

There is an exercise 9.3#1 from "Topology without tears":

Let $(X_i, d_i), i\in \mathbb{N}$, countable infinity of metric spaces, where every metric is bounded: $\forall X_i\forall a, b \in X_i, d_i(a, b) \le 1$

Let
$D_1, D_2=(\prod_{n=1}^\infty(X_i)\times\prod_{n=1}^\infty(X_i)) \to \mathbb{R}$, two metrics on product space

$$D_1\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty(a_i),\prod_{n=1}^\infty(b_i)\right)=\sup \{d_i(a_i, b_i): i \in \mathbb{N}\} $$

$$D_2\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty(a_i),\prod_{n=1}^\infty(b_i)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d_i(a_i, b_i)}{2^i} $$

We need to show their equivalence (equivalence of topologies induced by this metrics)

But how could this metrics induce the same topologies? Second one induce usual countable product topology, with base $O_1\times O_2 \times ... \times O_n\times X_{n+1}\times X_{n+2} \times ...$ (where $O_i$ is any set from the base of $X_i$)

and first should induce box topology, $O_1\times O_2 \times ... \times O_n\times O_{n+1}\times O_{n+2} \times ...$  (this is not correct, I think, but I don't understand why — i.e. if we imagine open ball of radius 0.5, it will be a product of open balls of radius 0.5 on every $X_i$, and this ball will be always a subset of $X_i$, not equal to $X_i$)

So, what i miss?

Comment: "How could this two metrics be equal?" Literally equal?

Comment: No, sorry, I mean "induce the same topology", I will change this now

Comment: Note that the box topology would not be first countable, while every metrizable space is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this exercise is wrong. Your remark about the open ball of radius $1/2$ being the products of open balls of radius $1/2$ is also wrong *in general* [it fails for $X_i=[0,1],\,\forall i$ and the usual Euclidean metric because $(\frac{1}{2}-2^{-i})_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is in the product of the open balls about zero but $\sup_i d(a_i,b_i)=1/2$ in this instance, not $<1/2$).

It is hopefully clear that the topology induced by $D_2$ is coarser than the topology induced by $D_1$. However, the converse inclusion is false. Your idea about the box topology works when there isn't a "continuum" of values attained by the metric, whatever that means; your idea about the box topology works in the counterexample below.

Take $X_i$ to be the discrete metric space on two points, for every $i\in\Bbb N$. The metric of $D_1$ on $\prod_i X_i=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ is again just the discrete metric; $d(a,b)=\begin{cases}1&a\neq b\\0&a=b\end{cases}$. This cannot be topologically equivalent to the product metric since the point $\{(0,0,0,\cdots)\}$ is open with respect to $D_1$ but is not open in the product topology.

Comment: This exercise as quoted by Bogdan is different from the current online version of the book, which now just asks you to show that the sup metric is a metric. Perhaps the author realised that an earlier version was wrong.

Comment: @RobArthan Interesting. You'll have to raise that with Bogdan since I don't have a copy. Maybe we could replace the exercise with the (significantly harder?) exercise of: *when* is $D_1$ equivalent to $D_2$? I'm not sure what the answer is off the top of my head

Comment: The book is available from the [author's website](https://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook2023.pdf).

Comment: @RobArthan, thank you very much for this observation! I used this version of book (also from theauthor's website, but probably older) https://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook.pdf

Comment: @FShrike thank you for the example, it's clear for me now why that topology it is not the box topology (and really, the new version of the book says that it is the uniform topology, not the product topology)